# wsadmin upload file to war

Tags: upload, websphere, websphere-7, wsadmin

is it possible to upload file using wsadmin (jacl/jython) to webapp module? (fe app.war/custom/uploadedfile.txt)?
I'm using wsadmin as standalone and want to do some postinstall step before start of application.

websphere 7

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/replace files with "AdminApp update file". Here's the doc for AdminApp:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminapp.html

.. and its options:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html

And here's the example:

```
AdminApp.update('TheAppName', 'file', ['-operation', 'add', '-contents', '/path/to/your/local/file', '-contenturi', 'path/within/the_app'])
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin, can I also upload file to server not only to application? For Example I'd like to upload file to <WAS_SERVER>/lib. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266486/wsadmin-upload-file-from-local-machine-to-remote/13283903#13283903